# Similar Variable Names

Tags: variable

I have variables $X1,...,X10$ and $X1hat,..., X10hat$ in a system of equations. How can I refer to these variables in a summation? I am looking for something like:

```
Sum[X`i' X`i'hat,{i,10}]
```

Comment: Instead of `x1`, use `x[1]`. Then you can use `x[i]`.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem for variables. But is there also a way to do something similar for an equation to avoid writing it multiple times? For example instead of writing eq1=X[1]^2,...,eq10=X[10]^2, write something like:  {eq[i] = X[i]^2, {i, 10}} in a system of equations?

Comment: Use `Table` to make a list of equations.